# Android NDK MediaDrm getKeyRequest doesn't return URL

Tags: android, android-ndk, drm, playready

I'm using the MediaDrm API for PlayReady decryption.

I've noticed the NDK `AMediaDrm_getKeyRequest` method doesn't return the `defaultUrl` to use to send the request.

There seems to be a contradiction in the documentation (See [NdkMediaDrm.h line 154](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/e91e44dc29517115794a72eea554616d067925ae/ndk/platforms/android-L/arch-arm64/usr/include/media/NdkMediaDrm.h#154)) as to whether or not it is returned, likely copied over from the Java documentation.

Has anyone managed to get the url with `AMediaDrm_getKeyRequest`? Or found another way to obtain the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is inside the `<LA_URL>` tags in the playready header :)